Increase timeStamp during Anchor Test cases of TS(typescipt)
How to increase timeStamp during Anchor Test cases of TS(typescipt),
I have use sinon pkg but It's not happening
const clockStub =  sinon.stub(Date, 'now').returns(Date.now() + (15 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)); // Add 15 days in milliseconds
What are the other ways?

From my understanding, you need to get 15 days from now.
JavaScript's Date API is pretty robust and you can use it without the need to add new packages to your project.
const now = new Date();
const fifteenDaysLater = new Date(now.getTime() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

// unix timestamp
const timestamp = Math.floor(fifteenDaysLater.getTime() / 1000);
 
console.log('Unix Timestamp', timestamp);


I did this thing too , but It wont work while processing the txs over solana , since every state is being managed by accounts, so the test cases over solana will be wont work while increasing the timestamp.
What I will do is to get start writing test cases using rust instead of TS/JS
check this link

I misunderstood your question. To manipulate state checkout soloana bankrun https://github.com/kevinheavey/solana-bankrun

Any idea how could I do while processing the txs,like If I increase the time stamp before initialize function, this function has a field
pub clock : Sysvar<'info,Clock>
how can this record that increaseTimestamp and after I ran the tx the timestamp I found was not increase during typescript testcases

check out the docs https://kevinheavey.github.io/solana-bankrun/. I haven't used bankrun yet
